# responsive wordpress columns from scratch

Tags: wordpress, multiple-columns

I'm developing a custom wordpress theme and currently using the column shortcodes plugin to achieve columns but they aren't working well. For example, they suddenly stopped going across the browser and will now only display one on top of the other except for on one page where they will work if a  is placed between the shortcodes (where it should not be placed, nor was div even opened...this was typo that is now the only way to make the shortcode columns display properly). I wasn't working on any code when they started acting weird, so I'm not sure what's happening.

If anyone has experienced this with column shortcodes, let me know. Otherwise, I'm looking for a tutorial or something to teach me how to create well-coded, responsive columns that work in wordpress without using a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend working with a framework like bootstrap/foundation or lightweight framework like skeleton.

shoelace.io create responsive columns for bootstrap.

If you only support modern browsers try CSS3 columns http://html5css3box.com/multiple-columns/